# DataTable: Hide the Show Entries dropdown but keep the Search box

Tags: datatable, dt

Is it possible to hide the Show Entries dropdown but keep the Search box in DataTable? I want to always display 10 rows with pagination at the bottom along with search box but do not want to display the Show entries dropdown.

Answer (score 350, accepted):

You can find more information directly on this link: http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/filter_only.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false });
});
```

EDIT : If you are lazy, "bLengthChange": false, is the one you need to change :)

Answer (score 87):

If using Datatable > 1.1.0 then `lengthChange` option is what you need as below :

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "lengthChange": false
});
```

Comment: Yes, documented here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange

Answer (score 50):

```
"searching": false,   // Search Box will Be Disabled

"ordering": false,    // Ordering (Sorting on Each Column)will Be Disabled

"info": true,         // Will show "1 to n of n entries" Text at bottom

"lengthChange": false // Will Disabled Record number per page
```

Answer (score 24):

This is **key** answer to this post `"bLengthChange": false,` will hide the Entries Dropdown

Answer (score 14):

I solve it like that. Use bootstrap 4

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table').DataTable({
            "searching": false,
            "paging": false,
            "info": false
        });
    });
```

cdn js:

- https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
- https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
- https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
- https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js

cdn css:

- https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css
- https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css

Comment: This works for datatables in 2018, none of the other did.

Answer (score 11):

Just write :

```
  $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
          "lengthChange": false
        } );
    } );
```

Answer (score 10):

For DataTables <=1.9, [@perpo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285488/1771644)'s answer

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false
});
```

works fine, but for 1.10+ try this:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "dom": 'ftipr'
});
```

where we have left out `l` the "length changing input control"

[1.9 Docs](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features)

[1.10 Docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

Comment: this is better because it remove the div holdint the element . with bLenghChange element is gone but there is whitespace . thanks !

Answer (score 8):

sDom: "Tfrtip" or via a callback:

```
"fnHeaderCallback": function(){
    $('#YOURTABLENAME-table_length').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To disable the "Show Entries" label, add the code dom: 'Bfrtip' or you can add "bInfo": false

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip'
})
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this also.

simply hide it from CSS by using,

```
 .dataTables_length {
        display: none;
    }
```

Both will work.

Answer (score 1):

Add this option:

```
"bInfo": false
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide "show entries" but still have pagination. I used the code below and it worked.

```
"bPaginate": true,
"bLengthChange": false,
"bFilter": true,
"bInfo": false,
"bAutoWidth": false
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the "Show Entries" label, use "bInfo", example:
"bFilter" is the search component, but are active by default.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bInfo": false
  } );
} );
```

Enable or disable the table information display. This shows information about the data that is currently visible on the page, including information about filtered data if that action is being performed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular you can use the following code to do the same.

in component.html

```
<table id="" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table dataTable">
```

and in your component.ts

```
 dtOptions: any = {}


 this.dtOptions = {
  searching: true,    //enables the search bar
  info: false        //disables the entry information
}
```

there more option for data table available
please visit [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/) to learn more

Answer (score 0):

for specific pages i suggest you use pure css --

```
.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info, .dataTables_paginate, .dataTables_length 
    { 
     display: none;
    }
```

The above code will hide everything.